# Difference between Root Value And Context in express GraphQL

Tags: node.js, graphql

I was going through GraphQL-Express docs and in those docs there was a definition for rootValue and Context which looks like this

> **rootValue**: A value to pass as the rootValue to the graphql() function
>   from GraphQL.js/src/execute.js.
>
> **context**: A value to pass as the context to the graphql() function from
>   GraphQL.js/src/execute.js. If context is not provided, the request
>   object is passed as the context.

Now, Can someone explain me the difference between rootValue and context above?

Also, Since my new to Express-and-GraphQL as well.

The example I read on the web, There the person did something like this

```
// GraphQL setup
app.use("/user", async  (req, res) => graphqlHTTP({
  schema: userSchema, //TODO: Change it authentication once it is ready
  graphiql: true,
  context: {req, res}
})(req, res))
```

Notice the  `})(req, res))` in the above line which looks like this which I believe is an annyonmousfunction which gets called by itself?

In the official express GraphQL example, I wasn't able to find anything like that i.e Quoting from the official docs

```
app.use(
  '/graphql',
  graphqlHTTP(async (request, response, graphQLParams) => ({
    schema: MyGraphQLSchema,
    rootValue: await someFunctionToGetRootValue(request),
    graphiql: true,
  })),
```

Here why haven't we used anonymous function? Is it because of passing value to context vs passing value to root?

Answer (score 4):

In GraphQL.js, context is a service-specific object that is passed to *every* resolver in your schema. It's built on a per-request basis and so can include things like session information, information about the user making the request, etc. It's also commonly used for dependency injection. For example, you'll commonly see database models passed to context so they are accessible inside resolvers without having to `require` their modules.

Every resolver is passed the value its *parent* field resolved to as its first parameter. In the case of *root level fields* like those on the `Query` or `Mutation` types, there is no parent field. The `root` value is simply the value that's passed to those resolvers. There is, in my opinion, rarely ever a need to provide any values through the root value.

Express makes use of [middleware functions](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) that accept either three parameters (req, res, next) or four parameters (error, req, res, next). What you pass to `app.use` should be a middleware function. The `graphqlHTTP` function itself is *not* a middleware function -- it returns a middleware function.

Consider the following examples:

```
const foo = (req, res, next) => {
  res.status(200)
}
app.use(foo)

// Here the function inside app.use is the actual middleware, but it passes
// the values it receives to foo
app.use((req, res, next) => foo(req, res, next))

// This returns a middleware function
const bar = () => {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    res.status(200)
  }
}
// Notice we have to call bar first, just like we do with graphqlHTTP
app.use(bar())

// We can "wrap" bar inside another middleware function like we did with foo
app.use((req, res, next) => bar()(req, res, next))
```

These four examples are equivalent in that they all do the same thing (set the status to 200 on the request).

Given a middleware function, or a function that returns one, it's *usually* not necessary to "wrap" or "nest" it inside another one. However, in your example, we want access to `req` and `res` before we call `graphqlHTTP` to generate the actual middleware function that will be used, so we have to do this.

*However*, this is also unnecessary because `graphqlHTTP` itself accepts a function that's passed the `req` and `res` values as parameters. I think at one point the `res` was not included in the callback function so this was an appropriate workaround in those cases.